# How to pass a variable and value after a successful transaction before redirecting to the page of my choice

Tags: php, paypal, eclipse-pdt

I was planning to use the PDT function of PayPal standard checkout to redirect to a page of my choice with  a variable with a value  written in PHP to hide from display source page. However the manual they claim to clarify this issue doesn't have anything to the with it and is about Paypal payment pro plan.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I entirely understand your question, but PDT would be used with Website Payments Standard, it would not be used with Website Payments Pro.  Basically PDT returns the information to the page your set up, and then you would do a POST back to PayPal to verify the data.  The PDT returns the information/variables via a GET method.